# Info from one web app to another

Tags: security, web-applications, local-storage

I apologise if this is a newbie question!!

I'm building a web app and I'd like to be able to send stored local data from an instance of the web app on my phone to another instance of the same web app on another phone and save it to local data there. The caveat is that it can't get sent through http to my server as it contains sensitive information. I also don't want to store it on a web server in any form as I don't want to manage the security of the web server in terms of storing this sensitive information.

At the moment then only solution I can come up with is for the web app to generate an email which is sent to the second device, and then copy and pasted into the web app. Very clunky. Any ideas?